# Git: Branch back in time (and switch head)

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Last week, I started a new project that uses an Opensource library. I discovered a bug in that library, forked it on Github, fixed the bug, and submitted a PR. I received some comments and did more commits to update my PR:

```
|-my commit 3  <- master (PR#1)
|-my commit 2
|-my commit 1
|-commit x     <- remote:master
...
```

While waiting for my PR to be merged, I discovered another bug, created a bug report, branched at commit x, committed a fix and created another PR:

```
|-my commit 3     <- master (PR#1)
|-my commit 2
|-my commit 1
| |-my commit 4   <- fix_bug_2 (PR#2)
|/
|-commit x        <- remote:master
...
```

So I should probably better have branched before doing my first commit. Is there any way I can get fix it, so that I can easily track upstream while creating more PRs for new bugs I find without messing up my existing PRs? It should look like this:

```
|-my commit 3     <- fix_bug_1 (PR#1)
|-my commit 2
|-my commit 1
| |-my commit 4   <- fix_bug_2 (PR#2)
|/
|-commit x        <- master, remote:master
...
```

Something like:

- create new branch "fix_bug_1" at commit x
- switch master with fix_bug_1
- make sure PR#1 still contains the same commits as before

Or should I simply wait until PR#1 gets merged and from now on always remember not to work on head?

Comment: Is what you call `head` actually a branch, named `main` or `master` ?

Comment: Your alternative diagrams are identical topologically. It's hard to see what the problem is. PRs should not depend on each other so what you're doing looks fine.

Comment: @matt the commits are identical, but the branch names are not

Comment: But branch names are just names.

Comment: @LeGEC Yes, fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a branch named `fix_bug_1` at "the same commit as `master`" :

```
git branch fix_bug_1 master
```

To forcibly move `master` to where `origin/master` is :

```
git branch -f master origin/master
```

---

As far as I know, there is no way in github to change the "source branch" of a PR, you would have to create a new PR to track your new branch.

Comment: Will that keep PR#1 intact, so that it then contains my 3 commits?

Comment: Well, if you force-push that new `master` then PR#1 will get messed up.

Comment: Ok thank you. They already merged my PR in the meantime, so I think I can clean up now.